# HDMI not detected - Compatibility between processor and Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I've been facing several problems since my installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I originally was on Ubuntu 18.04 and downgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 to be able to work with ROS Kinetic. Now, I have no access to the back-light, or, worst, the HDMI port, it is not even detected (whereas it was on Ubuntu 18 and still works on Windows obviously). I have no drivers detected on the additional driver page of software&updates.

- My graphic card is Intel HD Graphics 620
- Processor : i5 8th generation
- Kernel : 4.4.0-21-generic

I thought it might come from a problem of compatibility but my knowledge in Linux is not enough to be able to understand the actual source of the problem.

If anyone had any clue, it would really be helpful
Thanks

Comment: HDMI not being detected is not a processor/CPU issue.  That's a graphics / video driver problem typically.

Comment: That's a pretty old kernel, try updating your system and see if the problem goes away.  Note, launchpad bug #1755309 for HDMI sound problems (cannot compile the driver) caused by an Ubuntu kernel header bug (guess someone grabbed a release candidate, and didn't notice the final release was changed).

Comment: Thank you very much ! It was a problem of kernel, after updating it, everything works better. I still have a problem with the wifi, I can see the networks but it does not connect. The card is a realtek, it seems like it involves many problems working with Ubuntu